# I am trying to use chain link using remix

Tags: solidity, remix, error, external-api, chainlink

[image]

I'm getting this error

```
/*
Internal exception in StandardCompiler::compile: /root/project/libsolidity/interface/CompilerStack.cpp(93): Throw in function solidity::frontend::CompilerStack::CompilerStack(ReadCallback::Callback)
Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<solidity::langutil::InternalCompilerError>
std::exception::what: You shall not have another CompilerStack aside me.
[solidity::util::tag_comment*] = You shall not have another CompilerStack aside me.
*/
```

What do I need to do?

Here is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

   
    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

  
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. You are using a very, very old version of Remix from a few years ago (0.7.7 - current is 0.11.5.) I'm not sure how you've managed to access it, but I suspect that is the cause of the problem...

Comment: How did you get this version of remix?

Comment: I had just referred to chainlink docs

Comment: chainlink seems to be very buggy and broken sadly. I don't think it works with remix